# Calling a method in an Optional 3rd Party DLL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, dll

I am working on an add-on component that needs to play nice with other similar add-ons. There is a 3rd party component that decided to implement the functionality a little differently than the default.

What I am trying to do is call an overload of a method that only the 3rd party component has, like this:

```
Select Case True
    Case TypeOf provider Is 3rdParty.Provider
        result = DirectCast(provider, 3rdParty.Provider).GetNames(method, True)
    Case Else
        result = provider.GetNames(method)
End Select
```

Unfortunately, the DLL that contains 3rdParty.Provider is optional, so this code will give compile errors if it is not present. How can I accomplish the same thing but make it safe to run whether the 3rdParty.Provider.dll is present or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error and going through several MSDN docs and forum posts, I was able to piece together the following solution:

```
Dim t As Type = Type.GetType("3rdParty.Provider, 3rdParty.Provider")
Select Case True
    Case Object.ReferenceEquals(provider.GetType(), t)
        result = Convert.ChangeType(provider, t).GetNames(method, True)
    Case Else
        result = provider.GetNames(method)
End Select
```

I tested removing the 3rd party DLL reference from my project and this works without a hitch and calls the default GetNames in that case without any exceptions or compile errors.

Comment: Nice to know. Even your solution is ok, I was only suggestion one that's more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You need inversion of control for this.

Check Castle Windsor or Microsoft Unity projects.

These will provide you a way to switch implementations of same base type by configuration.

http://www.castleproject.org/container/

http://unity.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hmm..."switch implementations of same base type by configuration" doesn't sound at all like what I am trying to achieve. I took a look at each of those links and honestly, I don't know where to begin. I was pretty much expecting the answer to involve a simple check with reflection to see if the type exists.

Comment: That reflection solution would end in reinventing the wheel. These API give you a chance to do what you want to do with zero effort in terms of invent wheels. Take a look to: http://socialcloud.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/59263#1320643 (it's one of my personal projects, check the "Components" section). You can see there that you can map abstract classes or interfaces to a concrete implementation of them. Then, using that is easy as IWindsorContainer.Resolve<IYourInterface>("some identifier") and you get an instance of whole implementation.

Comment: Now I have gone from fairly certain this is not a solution to absolutely certain. I don't have access to the config files of users of my component and making them do brain surgery on web.config just in case they buy this other third party component is certainly not an attractive option - this is a support nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: That's wrong: Castle Windsor supports embedded configuration files. Or you can programatically populate a container.

Comment: Well, if I run across another project where I have more than 3 lines of code that reference a optional 3rd party component, perhaps I will take another look. For this project, I would prefer not to add any dependencies and adding an extra dll to replace 3 lines of code is overkill. Not to mention, the amount of documentation I would have to go through to make heads or tails of it seems pretty extreme considering my situation.

Comment: Understandable, it was just a suggestion. If you found a solution that fits your needs, this is the way to go, isn't it?

Comment: Since I have posted this I have become somewhat of an expert in DI, but I still think your answer is not relevant to this question. DI is for composing applications. What I am doing here is building a control library which is unaware of how the application is configured. Using DI also requires all of the dependent objects to conform to the *same* interface. This specific case is to call a 3rd party library (that may or may not be referenced) that is using a *different* interface than the original. DI is a great tool, but not for this job.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I'm not sure if you're right or not, because your original question had few background details... Why don't you ask a new question to validate your approach w/o IoC?